# c# - How to list all the properties of a class that are list of a given interface and call a method

Tags: c#

I have 3 interfaces defined as below:

```
public interface IInt1 : IMyGeneric
{}
public interface IInt2 : IMyGeneric
{}
public interface IMyGeneric
{
void Update();
}
```

Then I have a class that uses the above:

```
public class MyClass
{
public List<IInt1> myList1;
public List<IInt2> myList2;
public List<double> myList3;
void MyUpdate()
{
// code must go here
}
```

In the "MyUpdate" method I would like to call the "Update" of each element of myList1 and myList2.
"MyUpdate" should be able to find by itself which properties are list of the "IMyGeneric" class.
I know I should use the Reflection, but I don't know how...

Comment: To get the properties of the object a method of that objects class is being executed on, you would use `GetType().GetProperties(...)`, specifying some BindingFlags for which kinds of properties you want to include.

Comment: Can't use an abstract class?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Why reflection? all the elements within the lists are statically typed instances of `IInt1` or `Int2`, which define `Update`.

Comment: just iterate the lists and call `Update` for every element? Where's the problem?

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the answers; as written in the initial request, "MyUpdate should be able to find by itself which properties are list of the "IMyGeneric" class.", so I don't want to manually select wich "myList" implements "MyGeneric".
If, for example, next week myList3 becomes of type IInt2, I don'T want to manually modify the "MyUpdate."
I'll try with the suggestion from @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<IInt1> myList1;
public List<IInt2> myList2;
public List<double> myList3;
void MyUpdate()
{
   foreach(item in myList1)
   {
      item.Update()
   }
   // Same for list2
}
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you for the answers; as written in the initial request, "MyUpdate should be able to find by itself which properties are list of the "IMyGeneric" class.", so I don't want to manually select wich "myList" implements "MyGeneric".
If, for example, next week myList3 becomes of type IInt2, I don'T want to manually modify the "MyUpdate."